# É possível usar IF dentro do FROM no MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Seria possível fazer `IF` dentro do `FROM`?
Procurei mas não consegui achar nada a respeito.

Segue um exemplo do que quero fazer:

```
SELECT usuario.* FROM (
  SELECT
  IF( 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pessoa) > 0, 
    SELECT  FROM pessoa,
    SELECT * FROM clliente, 
  ) AS usuario
)
```

OBS: Como a arquitetura do banco foi desenvolvida da pior forma, estou tendo que fazer umas loucuras no SQL.

Comment: Eu tenho quase certeza que não (porque eu acabei de testar aqui), mas tenho certeza do que o que você precisa pode ser feito de outra maneira. Você tem algum exemplo real do que você precisa fazer com isso?

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução pode ser criar uma view

```
create or replace view v_pessoa_cliente
as
select cpf , nome from pessoa
union
select cpf,nome from cliente
```

Na aplicação faça

```
select *
from v_pessoa_cliente
where nome = 'Daniel Dutra'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplificando assim já não resolveria o seu caso?

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(p.*) > 0, p.*, c.*) as usuarios_maior_volume
FROM pessoas p, clientes c;
```

E para pegar global:

```
SELECT * FROM pessoas, clientes;
```

E para trazer tudo:

```
SELECT * FROM pessoas
union all
SELECT * FROM clientes;
```

Comment: Não obtive sucesso, apresenta erro de versão do MySql.
version: 5.0.95-log; version_bdb: Sleepycat Software: Berkeley DB 4.1.24: (December 16, 2011)